interceptors when pages refreshes
My refresh scenario works fine, but i only call the interceptor when the user changes so after i login, but when i refresh the page the userRef will be empty and also the interceptor won't be called
i've tried a use effect on mount when the token is available on my local storage but it still didn't work for me
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState("");
  const userRef = useRef(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userRef.current) {
      setupAxiosInterceptors();
    }
  }, [userRef.current]);

  //Login Handler
  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/login", {
        email,
        password,
      });

      const { accessToken, refreshToken } = response.data;
      localStorage.setItem("token", accessToken);

      const decodedUser = jwtDecode(accessToken);
      userRef.current = { ...decodedUser, refreshToken };
      console.log("user refresh Token: ", userRef.current.refreshToken);

      setErrorMessage("");
      setSuccessMessage("Logged in successfully.");

      setTimeout(() => {
        navigate("/dashboard");
      }, 500);
    } catch (error) {
      if (
        error.response &&
        (error.response.status === 400 || error.response.status === 500)
      ) {
        setErrorMessage("Credentials not correct. Please try again.");
        setSuccessMessage("");
      } else {
        console.error("Login error:", error);
        setErrorMessage("Failed to log in. Please try again later.");
        setSuccessMessage("");
      }
    }
  };

  //Generate a new token
  const refreshAccessToken = async () => {
    try {
      if (!userRef.current || !userRef.current.refreshToken) {
        throw new Error("Refresh token not available");
      }

      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/refresh-token",
        { token: userRef.current.refreshToken }
      );
      const newAccessToken = response.data.accessToken;
      localStorage.setItem("token", newAccessToken);
      console.log("New access token set ... ");
      return newAccessToken;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // axios interceptor
  const setupAxiosInterceptors = () => {
    axios.interceptors.request.use(
      async (config) => {
        let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        if (!token) {
          throw new Error("Token is not available");
        }
        const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
        const tokenExpiry = decodedToken.exp * 1000;
        const currentDate = new Date().getTime();
        // Compare token expiry with current time
        setTimeout(async () => {
          if (tokenExpiry - 5000 < currentDate) {
            token = await refreshAccessToken();
            console.log("New token:", token);
            config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
            console.log("Token refreshed successfully");
          }
        }, 1000);

        return config;
      },
      (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
  };
  return (
    <div className="text-center">
      <form
        onSubmit={handleLogin}
        className="flex flex-col gap-4 items-center *:w-[300px] *:rounded-md *:border-2 *:border-solid *:border-green-600 *:indent-2 *:text-black mt-10"
      >
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Login"
          className="bg-red-500 border-none font-bold"
        />
      </form>
      {errorMessage && <span className="text-red-700">{errorMessage}</span>}
      {successMessage && (
        <span className="text-green-700">{successMessage}</span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;


